# VS2008 Load Testing - Maximum page counters = 50?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, load-testing

We have just discovered that Visual Studio 2008 load testing appears to count and report on only the first 50 unique pages used in a given load test.  This is obviously fairly useless for load tests that hit more than 50 different pages on a web server.

Is this a hard restriction or is this perhaps configurable somewhere in the registry?

Does anyone know if the same limitation exists in Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 1):

After checking with Microsoft, it looks like this is simply a limitation of the controls used on the load test results page.

It appears that all request results are in the load test database but the on-screen graph and the export is limited to 50 unique requests.

Microsoft has confirmed that this issue no longer exists in VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2010 you can configure the number of urls reported by the Load Test Runconfig option "Maximum Request URLs Reported". Default value is 1000.

Comment: We are using VS2008 which has such a setting per load test "run settings" and it's already defaulted to 1000. Puzzled.  Here is what our "run settings" looks like. http://i40.tinypic.com/a0wbbk.jpg

Comment: How long are your requests ? If the requests are very long then its possible they might be trimmed when inserted into the DB due to which multiple requests with same prefix might have single entry. VS2010 should not have this problem.  I would suggest trying that out.